# Где должна выполняться логика в redux? В action или в reducer?

Tags: javascript, redux

Верно ли утверждение, что `reducer` должен только приминать состояние, и на основе `type` менять его на основе предыдущего состояния.
А логика которая пишется для того что бы изменить само  состояние находится в `action creator`?

Comment: ну  редьюсер точно не подходит.  на самом старте логику размещали в action, но потом весь движ ушел в redux-thunk  а потом в redux-saga . по идее лучше всего (моё личное мнение) - саги.  очень удобно и понятною. получается   что  вся  бизнес логика отделена от view и это более удобно чем все  хламить в куче.

Answer (score 0):

> Верно ли утверждение, что reducer должен только приминать состояние, и
>   на основе type менять его на основе предыдущего состояния.

по сути, Вы можете что угодно делать внутри **reducer** и оно может работать. но это не правильно. пускай **reducer** обновляет состояние, а *что-то другое* делает другую работу. верьте, так удобно и к этому все привыкли.

> А логика которая пишется для того что бы изменить само состояние
>   находится в action creator?

**action creator** - это функция, которая создает объект (с **type** и **payload**) в виде инструкций для **reducer**, указывая как должен измениться **state**. Вы так же можете можете внутри **action creator** писать что угодно, любые действия, но зачем? так тоже никто не делает. пускай каждый механизм делает свою работу. для "промежуточных" действий Вам как раз нужен **middleWare** (**thunk**, **saga**). **middleWare** позволяет Вам создать функцию, внутри какой Вы можете объединить множество вызовов **action creators** и любых других действий.

> по идее лучше всего (моё личное мнение) - саги.

это частично верный комментарий, но не совсем. **redux-thunk** используется там, где есть простая логика изменения состояния. **redux-saga** используется для более сложных вещей